# How to get bluetooth device name if device dose not advertise it

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I tried to display bluetooth device list with names.

I get devices name from `centralManager(_ central:, didDiscover peripheral:, advertisementData:, rssi RSSI:)`

but some devices doesn't contains name in advertisementData, and I can't get it via `peripheral.name`

in this case I can connect to this device and discover it services, after discovering some service `peripheral.name != nil`

in this two case I am able to get device name, but there is third case
when I can't connect to device via `central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)`, delegate method simply doesn't calls, but I can open iOS device settings, go to bluetooth and there is this not connectable device with name.

Is there way to get this device name?

Comment: hmm, I am not sure if I understood your question very well; because you should be able to connect via the identifier.

Comment: but for some reason when I try to connect, CBPeripheralDelegate methods doesn't calls